# I am getting "bash: airflow: command not found"

Tags: debian, google-compute-engine, airflow

I am getting

> -bash: airflow: command not found

after installing [Apache Airflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Airflow). I am using Google Cloud Compute Engine and OS is Debian 9 (Stretch).

I have followed the below steps:

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow

pip install apache-airflow
```

Comment: I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18. You need to use "sudo pip install apache-airflow" as you have written

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I have uninstalled Apache Airflow and installed it with the `sudo` command (i.e., `sudo pip install apache-airflow`). After that it worked fine.

Comment: command to uninstall : pip3 uninstall apache-airflow

Answer (score 15):

If installed with *[sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)*, as [mentioned by Sirajus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51122849/getting-bash-airflow-command-not-found/51209922#51209922), it will be placed in */usr/local/bin/*.

Without *sudo*, it will be placed in the *~/.local/bin/* folder. This folder will not be added to the PATH environment variable automatically.

So you can either add it to the PATH environment variable or install it using *sudo*.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please consider using the code format for your bash commands. cheers.

Comment: It also depends on the location of Python installation, in my case Python was installed in  `/mnt/vol1/python3.7` and airflow binary was present here `/mnt/vol1/python3.7/bin/airflow`

Answer (score 1):

Post install, re-load environment variable and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Where does your pip install Apache Airflow to? It could be to */usr/local/bin* or similar.

Make sure that that directory is in your $PATH.

This isn't related to Apache Airflow, just your environment setup.